# how to change to angular material 2 mat-card background color in two different components

Tags: angular-material2

I have two different angular 6 components each with it own page. On each page there is a different list of mat-cards with different `mat-card-content` background color

although I change the color using the following code both pages have the same color (green), any suggestion how to customize the background color ?

```
list1.component.scss:
::ng-deep .mat-card-content {
  background-color: white 
}

list2.component.scss:
::ng-deep .mat-card-content {
  background-color: green 
}
```

tried with `!important;` without any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `:host` selector, the style is not encapsulated within the component's scope, so CSS rules apply: last one wins. Try:

```
list1.component.scss:
:host {
    ::ng-deep .mat-card-content {
      background-color: white 
    }
}

list2.component.scss:
:host{
    ::ng-deep .mat-card-content {
      background-color: green 
    }
}
```